# how do i limit the binary displayed in my decimal to binary converter?

Tags: c, binary, decimal, converters

I have this code so far:

```
for ( int i = 16; i >=0; i--){
   int k = n >> i;
   if (k & 1)
     printf("1");
   else
     printf("0");
}
```

I'm extremely new to C and I'm working on decimal to binary converter for a class. So far this is what I've found that works within my parameters. The only problem is I need this code to ONLY output the binary to the MSD which it was given.

As in if I have the decimal 15 it should display 1111 in binary, and if i have decimal 16 it should display only the next set of 4 above that, so 00010000.

As of right now i can set the amount to whatever i want, as in i = 16, but that would show 15 spaces total. where as if i put in a small decimal i don't want my program to show all the extra unnecessary 0's.

So is there a way to limit the binary output to correspond with say the most significant space necessary to accurately display its conversion?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: As for a possible way to solve your problem (as I understand it), you could find the highest non-zero [*nibble*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble) and start printing from that.

Comment: Off by one, why **16**? You're working with 17 bit numbers?

Comment: i'm working within a range of numbers between 0 and 65537. i've just been setting 'i = 15' to get the least bit shown from the maximum number.

Comment: That's a very odd range. 16 bit unsigned integers go from `0` to `65535` (inclusive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do so is to use a flag variable to check if we have a non-zero msb, and start printing 0 only after we encounter a non-zero msb e.g.

```
int flag
for ( int i = 16; i >=0; i--)
{
int k = n >> i;

if (k & 1){
  printf("1");
  flag = 1;
}else{
  if(flag)
    printf("0");
}
```

Comment: this worked amazingly well! thank you so much. one less problem i have to worry about now i just need to figure out how to get them in spaces of 4.

Comment: @AnonLaughingman Glad to help, you can click on the green tick which denotes that this answer solved your problem.

Comment: thanks for that information as well. now i'm off to ask my next question!

Answer (score 1):

To sort this in groups of 4, you need to work nibble by nibble. A function that prints a nibble (value 0 to 15 dec) could look like this:

```
void print_bin_nibble (uint8_t ls_nibble)
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    uint8_t bitmask = 1u << (4-1-i);
    printf("%c", (ls_nibble & bitmask) ? '1' : '0');
  }
  printf(" ");
}
```

Now if you want to print the data nibble-wise, while skipping leading zeroes for nibbles that equal 0000 bin, you need to keep track of if you should skip the printing with a boolean flag. The logic would be:

```
if(nibble==0 && remove_zeroes)
{
  ; // do nothing
}
else
{
  remove_zeroes = false;
  print_bin_nibble(nibble);
}
```

Which can be rewritten as (De Morgan's laws):

```
if(nibble != 0 || !remove_zeroes)
{
  remove_zeroes = false;
  print_bin_nibble(nibble);
}
```

Further consideration when printing a number is CPU endianess. There are various (bad) ways we can iterate over an integer byte by byte, such as using pointer arithmetic or unions. But then the output would be endianess dependent and look weird on little endian machines. By using bit shifts, we remove this portability issue completely, since they are endianess-independent.

For example given a 32 bit integer u32, we can mask out individual bytes like this:

```
(u32 >> (24-n*8)) & 0xFF
```

where `n` is the byte number 0 to 3. We end up shifting 24 bits for n=0, 16 bits for n=1, 8 bits for n=2 and 0 bits for n=3.

Full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void print_bin_nibble (uint8_t ls_nibble)
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    uint8_t bitmask = 1u << (4-1-i);
    printf("%c", (ls_nibble & bitmask) ? '1' : '0');
  }
  printf(" ");
}

void print_bin32 (uint32_t u32)
{
  bool remove_zeroes = true;

  for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof(u32); i++)
  {
    uint8_t byte = (u32 >> (24-i*8)) & 0xFF;
    uint8_t nibble;

    nibble = (uint32_t)byte >> 4;
    if(nibble != 0 || !remove_zeroes)
    {
      remove_zeroes = false;
      print_bin_nibble(nibble);
    }

    nibble = byte & 0xF;
    if(nibble != 0 || !remove_zeroes)
    {
      print_bin_nibble(nibble);
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main (void)
{
  print_bin32(16);
  print_bin32(0xDEADBEEF);
  print_bin32(0xABBA);
}
```

Output:

```
0001 0000
1101 1110 1010 1101 1011 1110 1110 1111
1010 1011 1011 1010
```

Comment: well this is completely beyond my grasp of C programming at the moment but i can make some of it out. i appreciate the information none the less but i'm shocked there doesn't seem to be an easier way to just sort your created binary number into increments of 4. not necessarily break it up into 4th but just make it limited to 4, 8, 16, 32 if it falls within that range. does that make more sense? like if its a number that's between 1 and 15 i'd like it to be displayed in 4 spaces. Seriously thanks for all this information though. I'm having fun sorting through it all.